# Reporting on Multiple Related Objects

Tags: reporting, joined-reports

I am trying to create a report that will allow me to have a scorecard for a center-of-influence (generally an accountant or attorney) showing incoming and outgoing referrals to/from this contact.

Our setup is such that 'Referral Source' is a lookup to Person-Account on the Opportunity object (this represents incoming referrals), and 'Outgoing Referral' as a custom object that is a child of Person-Account.

I would like to create a joint report that shows details about incoming and outgoing referrals grouped by center-of-influence. I have a report type for 'Outgoing Referrals with Referred CoI', but I have been unable to create a report type for 'Opportunities with Referral Source'.

Any ideas on how I can go about creating this scorecard/report without resorting to exporting multiple reports to Excel and combining them there?

Thanks!

Comment: So you want both to group on the Person Account?  Is Referral Source the PA or a different field?

Comment: If both child records are looking to a parent with master-detail relationships, you won't be able to I believe.

Comment: Mike: Referral Source is the PA


David: The referral source field is a Lookup to Person Account on the Opportunity object (this is for incoming referrals, or business referred to us), whereas Outgoing Referral is a custom object that has a lookup to Person Account (I misspoke earlier when I said it was master-detail).

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The join report should use the Report Types "Accounts with Outgoing Referrals" and "Accounts with Referred Opportunities". They both need to have Account at the top. Make sure in the second report type that you choose the correct Opportunity relationship, since you don't want to use the standard Opportunities list.

This will allow you to create a joined report showing both kinds of objects, grouped by the Person Account that either received a referred Opportunity or sent an Outgoing Referral.